How to prevent user from navigating to another page
I am making a project in React, TypeScript.
I cannot find how to stop a user from navigating to another page when there are unsaved changes. To make it clearer - I understand how to do the rest, I just need something that would stop it from processing until user confirmation.
Any links for solutions for V6 of React-Router would be appreciated. Also, I can try anything else instead of React-Router to solve it.
I made BeforeUnloadEvent, but it only works if a user reloads the page or navigates to another website.
If the user changes pages inside the app, it doesn't work.
I use:
"react": "^18.3.1",
"react-dom": "^18.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "^6.26.2",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
"typescript": "^5.6.2"

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

I tried different useEffects, something like:
useEffect(() => {
  if (isDirty) {          
    setIsOpen(true);
    setNextLocation(location.pathname);
  }
}, [location.pathname]);

But I do not understand how to add in there "stop or pause navigation".
Because it is v6 a lot of internet used-to-work solutions do not work for it, such as Prompt, usePropmpt, .listen, .block, BeforeUnload. Also, I tried
useBeforeUnload(
  useCallback(e => {
    if (isDirty) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return '';
    }
  }, [isDirty])
); 

but it would not stop navigation either (it does the same what BeforeUnloadEvent does).

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-blocker

Please also be aware that blocking navigation actions is not also generally considered to be a bit of an UI/UX anti-pattern. The recommendation is to simply take care of or clean things up when the component unmounts when it's navigated away from.

Thank you Drew. Can you please explain your comment about unmounting?  I am not sure that I know anything about it yet. What should I do better?

Component unmounting, like when the route it's rendered on changes and the UI is just navigating to another in-app page... versus the beforeunload event where the entire page (and app) is unloaded because either (a) the user refreshes the page or (b) is navigating away from your page/app entirely. See my answer here for an example for the recommendation to simply run a cleanup function in either case instead of entirely blocking navigations.

Have you tried using state variables to track changes and then based on the flag set, let the user navigate otherwise ask for confirmation?

maybe try implementing a custom hook that utilizes the useEffect hook along with the usePrompt approach??

As I mentioned, usePrompt doesn't work in v6. I tried also useBlocker but ran into the error "useBlocker must be used within a data router.", even though it is within the Router. I  might just follow the advice and instead of blocking the navigation, just save the data as a draft.

@Ira That's right, the useBlocker hook only works in Data routers, see Picking a Router.

I swapped to createBrowserRouter and it works for me now. I use useBlocker. Thank you.
